# How do you plug in exponent into coefficient?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to learn the chain rule. This question doesn't have too much specifically to do with the chain rule though, it's kind of algebra. Here it is: if you have let's say f'(x) = u^u and g(x) is an exponent, how would you plug that in to f'(x)? For the second u, you would just plug in g(x) because they're both exponents (right?) but how would you plug it into the first u? After the chain rule would it just be an exponent of an exponent (and with what base)? Please let me know if this makes no sense.

Comment: What is the relation between $u$ an $g(x)$?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to say.  ": if you have let's say f'(x) = uu[/quote] and g(x) is an exponent, how would you plug that in to f'(x)?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $f(x) = u^u$?

Comment: Yes 2ring my bad on that

Comment: This question is unintelligible. What does "$g(x)$ is an exponent" even mean? The way you've written it, $f'$ is a constant function, with $f'(x)=u^u$ for all $x$. Are you asking what $\frac{d}{dx} g(x)^{g(x)}$ is?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to say.  "if you have let's say f'(x) = uu"  Do you mean $u^2$? And how is u related to x?  Perhaps you mean $f'(x)= x^2$.
  "and g(x) is an exponent"
  Do you mean that you have something to the g(x) power?

"How would you plug that in to f'(x)?"
If you **mean** $f(u)= u^2$ and $u= e^x$.  Then $\frac{df}{dx}= \frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dx}= (2u)(e^x)= (2e^x)(e^x)= 2(e^x)^2= 2e^{2x}$

That could also be done as $f(x)= (e^x)^2= e^{2x}$ so that $\frac{df}{dx}= 2e^{2x}$ since the derivative of $e^{ax}$ is $ae^{ax}$ for any constant a.

Comment: It's simple, if g(x) is an exponent, any kind of exponent, and in order to complete the chain rule you need to plug it into f'(x), which equals (for example) u^u. How would you plug it into the first 'u' since g(x) is an exponent and the first 'u' is not?

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know if this makes no sense.

This makes no sense.  It might be that you're using phrases in a different way than they're conventionally used.  For instance, "how would you plug that into $f'(x)$?"  I'm not sure if you mean "how would you evaluate $f'(x)$ at $g(x)$?" (this is what *plug in* usually means), or "how would you complete the differentiation process?"

But I think you have a good question in there somewhere.  Your comment to user247327's answer is a clearer (albeit still not very clear) question:

> if $g(x)$ is an exponent, any kind of exponent, and in order to complete the chain rule you need to plug it into $f'(x)$, which equals (for example) $u^u$. How would you plug it into the first '$u$' since $g(x)$ is an exponent and the first '$u$' is not?

Here is a where a specific example of the $g(x)$ you're thinking about would help.  Because "$g(x)$ is an exponent" is another non-idiomatic phrase.  In an expression of the form $a^b$, the exponent is $b$ and the base is $a$.  The whole expression is called a *power*.  I'm going to guess you mean "$g(x)$ is a power function," or "$g(x)$ *has* an exponent."

So let me answer a question which I think might be related to your question:

> Suppose $f(u) = u^u$ and $g(x)=x^2$.  How do you use the chain rule to find the derivative of $f(g(x))$?

This is straightforward though not entirely simple.  The chain rule says we need to evaluate $f'(g(x))g'(x)$.  The second part *is* simple: $g'(x) =2x$.  As for the first, you may not have learned this yet, but:
$$
    f'(u) = (1+\ln u) u^u
$$
When we "plug in" $u=g(x)$, all that means is that we **replace any $u$ with $g(x)$**, or in this case, $x^2$.  It doesn't matter that $g(x)$ is a power function.
$$
    f'(g(x)) = (1 + \ln x^2)(x^2)^{x^2}
$$
So finally,
$$
    f'(g(x))g'(x) = (1 + \ln x^2)(x^2)^{x^2}(2x)
$$

---

**Appendix: The derivative of $u^u$**

For this one, you can use the identity $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$ and the product rule:
$$
  \frac{d}{du} u^u 
  = \frac{d}{du} e^{u \ln u}
  = e^{u\ln u}\left(u \cdot \frac{1}{u} + 1 \cdot \ln u\right)
  = u^u \left(1 + \ln u\right)
$$